# Debug samba point'n'print

Tags: drivers, printing, printer, samba

Two years ago I set up Samba 3.6.6 and cups (WinXP 32bit and Win7 64bit) with Point'n'Print using the CUPS drivers. It worked. Now I tried to connect to the printer from Win 10 and I get:

"No driver found. Windows cant find a driver for Kyocera on the network. To locate one manually, click OK. Otherwise, click Cancel and consult your network administrator or the printer manufacturer's website".

Is there any way to debug this?

To my knowledge, everything is OK:

```
# testparm
[...]
printcap name = cups
[...]
[print$]
    comment = Printer Drivers
    path = /etc/samba/drivers
    write list = root, admin
    create mask = 0644
    directory mask = 0755

[printers]
    comment = Alle Drucker
    path = /var/spool/samba
    guest ok = Yes
    printable = Yes
    print ok = Yes
    browseable = No

# find /etc/samba/drivers/
/etc/samba/drivers/
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/cups6.ini
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/minolta-bw.ppd
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/pscript5.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/minolta-color.ppd
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/ps5ui.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/cupsui6.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/cupsps6.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/Kyocera.ppd
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/pscript.hlp
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/3
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/3/pscript5.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/3/cupsps6.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/3/cupsui6.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/3/kyocera.ppd
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/3/minolta-bw.ppd
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/3/cups6.ini
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/3/pscript.ntf
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/3/minolta-color.ppd
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/3/ps5ui.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/3/Kyocera.ppd
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/3/pscript.hlp
/etc/samba/drivers/W32X86/pscript.ntf
/etc/samba/drivers/x64
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/ps5ui.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/cupsui6.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/cupsps6.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/3
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/3/ps5ui.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/3/pscript5.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/3/pscript.ntf
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/3/cups6.ini
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/3/Kyocera.ppd
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/3/pscript.hlp
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/3/minolta-bw.ppd
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/3/cupsps6.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/3/minolta-color.ppd
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/3/cupsui6.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/3/kyocera.ppd
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/cups6.ini
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/Kyocera.ppd
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/pscript.hlp
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/pscript5.dll
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/pscript.ntf
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/minolta-color.ppd
/etc/samba/drivers/x64/minolta-bw.ppd
```

All files are successfully accessible via `//server/print$`.
Drivers are shown successfully:

```
# rpcclient localhost -U admin -c 'enumdrivers'
Enter admin's password:

[Windows NT x86]
Printer Driver Info 1:
        Driver Name: [minolta-color]

Printer Driver Info 1:
        Driver Name: [minolta-bw]

Printer Driver Info 1:
        Driver Name: [kyocera]


[Windows x64]
Printer Driver Info 1:
        Driver Name: [minolta-bw]

Printer Driver Info 1:
        Driver Name: [minolta-color]

Printer Driver Info 1:
        Driver Name: [kyocera]
```

... and drivers are shown successfully to be linked to the printer:

```
# rpcclient localhost -U admin -c 'enumprinters'
Enter admin's password:
        flags:[0x800000]
        name:[\\LOCALHOST\minolta-bw]
        description:[\\LOCALHOST\minolta-bw,minolta-bw,Minolta QMS 2300DL, Black/White only]
        comment:[Minolta QMS 2300DL, Black/White only]

        flags:[0x800000]
        name:[\\LOCALHOST\minolta-color]
        description:[\\LOCALHOST\minolta-color,minolta-color,Minolta QMS 2300DL, Color print, high quality]
        comment:[Minolta QMS 2300DL, Color print, high quality]

        flags:[0x800000]
        name:[\\LOCALHOST\Kyocera]
        description:[\\LOCALHOST\Kyocera,Kyocera,Kyocera ECOSYS P6021cdn]
        comment:[Kyocera ECOSYS P6021cdn]
```

Comment: I currently encounter the same issue. Were you able to find a solution in the mean time?

Comment: Unfortunately not. Still interested in a solution!